# Ionic 4. Alternative for platform.lang()

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am checking the Platform docs (https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/platform) for ionic 4, i see that the lang() function which was available in ionic 3 (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/platform/Platform/) is not implemented.

Is there any alternative for this? I am trying to migrate an ionic 3 project to 4 where i have the following code to detect the user's language

`const browserLanguage = navigator.language || this.platform.lang();`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Globalization Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/globalization)

```
this.globalization.getPreferredLanguage()
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```